# Does "had" necessitate that someone is no longer in possession if something?

Tags: past-tense

The particular usage I'm curious about is "A man had four daughters." As in, he was the father of four girls. Does the usage of "had" necessitate that he no longer has any daughters (e.g. they all died)? I don't think so, but a friend disputes.

Comment: It is probably referring to the man in the past, not his daughters. "In 1984 I met a man, he had four daughters." Compare with "In 1984 I met a man, he has four daughters."

Comment: You might ask the same of your use of ***was***

Answer (score 3):

I would take "A man had four daughters" as meaning the same as "A man fathered four daughters".  It recounts events of fathering.  It doesn't have any particular implications about whether or not the man or any of his daughters still survives.

Comment: It depends on the context. 'A man had four daughters' sounds like the beginning of a story. As Greg says,  it could also be a statement of his place in a family tree (if you give his name). But if you are speaking of someone you know, you might say "He had four daughters, but sadly one died young."